# Setting a Variable inside a Running Thread to Stop the Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have an object `cooker` whose `run()` method starts a new thread `cookingThread`. After 5 seconds, how can I stop `cookingThread` by setting its variable `stopThread`?

Tried using `cooker.toggle()` to first start the thread, but the next `cooker.toggle()` was not able to stop the thread.

The following code gives me the error `NameError: global name 'cookingThread' is not defined`

```
import threading
import time

class Cooker(object):

    def __init__(self, recipe):
        self.active = False
        self.recipe = recipe

    def toggle(self):
        if not self.active:
            self.active = True
            self.run()

        else:
            self.active = False
            # How can this stop flag be passed into the running thread?
            cookingThread.stopThread = True


    def run(self):
        cookingThread = CookingThread(self.recipe)
        cookingThread.start()
```

**CookingThread**

```
class CookingThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, recipe):
        super(CookingThread, self).__init__()
        self.recipe = recipe
        self.stopThread = False

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.recipe):
            # Check if we should stop the thread
            if self.stopThread:
                return
            else:
                print 'Cooking...'
                time.sleep(1)
```

**Main**

```
cooker = Cooker(10)
cooker.toggle()    # Starts the thread

time.sleep(5)
cooker.toggle()    # Stops the thread (does not work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `cookingThread` is method scoped only inside `Cooker.run()` method. The error is saying that you need to declare it as global to be able to access from all the methods. But that is not a good practice.

What you can do is the following

```
import threading
import time

class Cooker(object):

    def __init__(self, recipe):
        self.active = False
        self.recipe = recipe

    def toggle(self):
        if not self.active:
            self.active = True
            self.run()

        else:
            self.active = False
            # How can this stop flag be passed into the running thread?
            self.cookingThread.stop()


    def run(self):
        self.cookingThread = CookingThread(self.recipe)
        self.cookingThread.start()
```

And changing the CookingThread as follow.

```
class CookingThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, recipe):
        super(CookingThread, self).__init__()
        self.recipe = recipe
        self.stopThread = False

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.recipe):
            # Check if we should stop the thread
            if self.stopThread:
                return
            else:
                print 'Cooking...'
                time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.stopThread = True
```

As a rule of thumb when developing Object Oriented Programming never access a field directly like in the case of `cookingThread.stopThread`. Try to use a method like `stop` actually to modify.

Comment: One issue with this solution is that if the thread is blocked waiting (rather the the time.sleep), it will not be able to check the stopThread flag. In those cases, killing the thread via signals or making the thread a daemon thread (see python daemon docs)